# Changing a column to nullable in a live database

Tags: sql-server

We have a requirement to change a column in a table, from not nullable to nullable.  The table crosses service domains and is being split up in line with our SOA needs.   Seems simple enough, but there are potentially huge consequences and impacts to our customers.

What possible ways can we rollback if there are any problems after we have run the scripts to make these changes?

If we were to rollback and there were null values how would you suggest to get things back into a decent state?

Given that we will be processing high volumes of transactions what strategies might be worth considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test, test again, test some more, and only let it hit production when you are absolutely sure.

In terms of rollback

- are there any defaults that could sensibly be used if you had to revert to not null?
- would you be able to restore a backup of the table and replay actions?

Comment: The defaults avenue has been discussed. Basically we are going to hand this off to a sql team and dev ops for release but they get jittery when there is no mitigation.   Restoring a backup would not be an option due to the 24 hour/worldwide operation of our site.

Comment: Its the right question for them to be asking - outside of testing, you  are after a back-out plan. Assuming that you still couldn't write out nulls - would the code still have a value it would of used instead? if so you could store that value as well to another column and use that in a backout.

Comment: All things being equal the values we are writing away "SHOULDNT" ever contain null "for the time being".  The persistence layer isnt being updated yet. So code isnt changed (services atop of the db will be doing this at some point in the future)   I guess I was thinking is there any reasonable justification for a rollback given these circumstances.....

Comment: The justification for it comes from "shouldn't" - you may need to prove that is "cannot" - otherwise the rollback requirement is a legitimate operational concern.